# Close PopOut window in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, window

I create popout window with new activity and this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_no_internet);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width*.8), (int) (height*.6));
}
```

I open it using:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopNoInternetActivity.class));
```

How can I close this popout?

Answer (score 0):

just write `getActivity.Finish();` OR `getApplicationContext().finish();` wherever you want to close this popout.

But its not a proper way, you have to use dialog not activity for this work. Hope it works. Thanx

Comment: I havent this methods in Main Activity. Maybe other way? :)